# Attribute error while using lambda in python

Tags: python, encryption, lambda

okay so here is my code so far:

```
import os
import time
import random
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

key = 'MIICWwIBAAKBgQDN'
print('do you have a encrypted string in a file?')
fileexist = input('if so then input 1:')
if fileexist == 1:
    filename = raw_input('please input path to file:')
    file = open(filename,'r')
    encoded = file.read()
    type = type(encoded)
else:
    encoded = raw_input('please enter encrypted text')
encoded = str(encoded)
BLOCK_SIZE = 16
PADDING = '{'
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)
decoded = DecodeAES(key, encoded)
print(decoded)
```

I keep geting a attribute error on line 24 my exact error message is as bellow

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decrpt'
```

I am trying to decrypt a message using AES. my encrypter works just fine using almost the exact same syntax. I dont fully understand the why the error apears. I know this is possible I have seen other post using this syntax.

Comment: It looks like there is either a typo in your code or the error message, where you are trying to 'decrpt' your string.  Check your spelling?

Comment: I am going off this code: http://www.codekoala.com/posts/aes-encryption-python-using-pycrypto/ by itself it works fine with a bit of editing but when I paste the lambda line into my code it errors out. I dont know what?

Comment: key is just a string in your code, which has no decrypt method.  Did you meant to set `key = AES.new('MIICWwIBAAKBgQDN')` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spelling issues set aside, in the code you link to, the first argument to `DecodeAES` is a `AES.AESCipher` object created with `AES.new` :

```
# create a cipher object using the random secret
cipher = AES.new(secret)
```

In your own code you are passing the string `key`, which doesn't have a `decrypt` method.

And FWIW this has nothing to do with the function being defined as a lambda - the function version would behave the very same way:

```
def DecodeAES(c, e): 
    return c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)


DecodeAES("foo", "bar")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in DecodeAES
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decrypt'
```

Comment: Okay thank you. This is my first time using lambda and I thought I had made a error while using that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create an AES object to pass in DecodeAES.

Do it using

```
key = 'MIICWwIBAAKBgQDN'
cipher = AES.new(key)
```

Now instead of calling `DecodeAES` on the `key`, you call it on the `cipher` object we created with the `key`:

```
decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encoded)
```

That should make your code working.